# BDC External Content Type Problem

Tags: 2013, bdc

I created BDC Model in VS 2012. After I deployed the project I can see ECT in BDC Service in Central Administration. But when I try to create an external content type I can see the external content type in list. It says

> The Business Data Connectivity metadata store is unavailable. Check
>   configuration and try again.

Why is this happening?

**Added:**

Pre-deployment and Post-deployment command line is empty in Project Properties(Sharepoint tab) . Should I write something in it?
In Active Deployment Configuration there is Default and No Activision. Mine is Default.
Feature1.Template.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Feature xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
</Feature>
```

Here is the Output:

> ------ Build started: Project: BDC, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Microsoft.Common.targets(1578,5):
>   warning MSB3270: There was a mismatch between the processor
>   architecture of the project being built "MSIL" and the processor
>   architecture of the reference "Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342,
>   processorArchitecture=AMD64", "AMD64". This mismatch may cause runtime
>   failures. Please consider changing the targeted processor architecture
>   of your project through the Configuration Manager so as to align the
>   processor architectures between your project and references, or take a
>   dependency on references with a processor architecture that matches
>   the targeted processor architecture of your project.   BDC ->
>   c:\Users\portalfarmadm\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\BDC\BDC\bin\Debug\BDC.dll   Successfully created package
>   at: c:\Users\portalfarmadm\Documents\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\BDC\BDC\bin\Debug\BDC.wsp
>
> ------ Deploy started: Project: BDC, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------ 
>   Active Deployment Configuration: Default
>   Skipping deployment step because a pre-deployment command is not specified.
>   Recycle IIS
>   Application Pool:
>   Recycling IIS application pool 'SharePoint -80'...
>   Retract Solution:
>   Retracting solution 'bdc.wsp'...
>   Deleting solution 'bdc.wsp'...
>   Add Solution:
>   Adding solution 'BDC.wsp'...
>   Deploying solution 'BDC.wsp'...
>   Activate Features:
>   No features in this solution were activated.
>   Skipping deploymentstep because a post-deployment command is not specified.
>   ========== Build: 1 succeeded or up-to-date, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
>   ========== Deploy: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========

**SOLVED**

I forgot to describe an Entity. So it can't deployed it.

Answer (score 1):

You have many things to check:

1. Services are properly configured and running - BDC and Managed
   metadata
2. Check if you BDC service app is actually associated with the Web App in which you are trying to use the ECT.
3. Permissions - go for the easy path - give access to everyone at the Model level and after solving it get back to reality.
4. Check your ULS Logs - or enable diagnostics prior to checking if not configured already.

Comment: How can I do step 2?

Comment: Step 2 is related to both the BDC and Managed Metadata. Under Manage Web Applications select your Web Application, you need to check in the Ribbon something with Service Connections Associations.

Comment: BDC and Managed Metadata Web Service is checked. As I see in ULS logs nothing goes wrong.

Comment: can you see your ECT via SharePoint designer?

Comment: No.I can't. but it is still in BDC service.

Comment: In managed metadata Proxy Properties, This service application is the default storage location for column specific term sets. is not checked. Should I check it.